# I have a JSON Response but can't parse it. Help Required. No JQUERY No Prototype. Just Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, callback

So I'm having some issus with JSON.

```
setupdata({"NON-RELIGOUS ORGANIZATIONS":{"23":["NON-RELIGOUS ORGANIZATIONS","Does this Loce test 2","",null]},"YARD SALES":{"1":["YARD SALES","yard sale","1332599400",null],"22":["YARD SALES","LOCKING TEST YARD SALE a change and more","1331814600",null],"21":["YARD SALES","Generic Yard Sale Title","",null]}})
```

And I'm processing it with....

```
function setupdata(data){

   alert(data.length);
   for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
   newdiv = document.createElement("DIV");
   newdiv.setAttribute("id","cat"+i);
   newdiv.innerHTML(\'test\');
   document.getElementById(\'divmiddle\').appendChild(newdiv);
   }
 }
```

I'm getting UNDEFINED for the data.length and also the i loop is not running because it is undefined. I guess I'm just a bit confused about how to parse through the data I return from the JSON call. Any help apppreciated.

**AND THE WINNING ANSWER IS**

Creating the Arrays in PHP:

```
while($getcats = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$layout[$getcats[news_cat_name]];
if(!$getstories = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT news_id,news_title,news_organization,news_expiration from news_items where news_category='$getcats[news_cat_id]'")){ echo mysqli_error($connection);}
while($looptitles=mysqli_fetch_array($getstories)){

$layout[$getcats[news_cat_name]][$looptitles[news_id]][]=date("m/d/y G:i a",$looptitles[news_expiration]);

 $layout[$getcats[news_cat_name]][$looptitles[news_id]][]=$looptitles[news_title];

$layout[$getcats[news_cat_name]][$looptitles[news_id]][]=$looptitles[news_organization];

}
}
```

**AND THE RESULTANT JSON**

```
setupdata({"NON-RELIGOUS ORGANIZATIONS":{"23":[false,"Does this Loce test 2","2"]},
"YARD SALES":{
     "1":["03\/24\/12 10:30 am","yard sale","0"]
     ,"22":["03\/15\/12 8:30 am","LOCKING TEST YARD SALE a change and more","0"],
     "21":[false,"Generic Yard Sale Title","0"]}})
```

**AND THE JS to PARSE THE JSON**

```
for(var key in data){//OUTER LOOP FOR THE MAIN OBJECTS
  divkey = document.createElement("DIV");
  divkey.setAttribute("id",key);
  divkey.style.fontSize = \'13px\';

  divkey.style.textDecoration = \'underline\';
  divkey.style.paddingTop = \'3px\';
  divkey.style.paddingBottom = \'5px\';
  divkey.style.position = \'relative\';
  divkey.innerHTML = key;
      document.getElementById(\'divmiddle\').appendChild(divkey);

  for(var mykey in data[key]){//INNER LOOP FOR THE INNER OBJECTS
         divkey = document.createElement("DIV");
     divkey.setAttribute("id",mykey);
         divkey.style.fontFamily = \'Verdana\';
         divkey.style.fontSize = \'11px\';
     divkey.style.paddingBottom = \'5px\';

     divkey.style.position = \'relative\';
     divkey.innerHTML = +data[key][mykey][1]+\' -- \' + data[key][mykey][0];
         document.getElementById(\'divmiddle\').appendChild(divkey);
   }
  }
 }
```

** I hope this helps someone with a complete solution since there are partial postings all over the place.**

Comment: alert(data["NON-RELIGOUS ORGANIZATIONS"]["23"].length);

Comment: are those backslashes in your actual code, or did those just sneak into this post somehow?

Comment: Yes those are backslashes because I coped out of the generating PHP file....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setupdata({ "NON-RELIGOUS ORGANIZATIONS": { "23": ["NON-RELIGOUS ORGANIZATIONS", "Does this Loce test 2", "", null] }, "YARD SALES": { "1": ["YARD SALES", "yard sale", "1332599400", null], "22": ["YARD SALES", "LOCKING TEST YARD SALE a change and more", "1331814600", null], "21": ["YARD SALES", "Generic Yard Sale Title", "", null]} });
   function setupdata(data) {
       alert(JSON.stringify(data));
       alert(data.length);
       for (var key in data) {
           alert(JSON.stringify(data[key]['23']));
           newdiv = document.createElement("DIV");
           newdiv.setAttribute("id", "cat" + data[key]['23']);
           newdiv.innerHTML = 'test';
           document.getElementById('divmiddle').appendChild(newdiv);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically `{}` is an `Object` not an `Array` so it's doesn't have `length` property.

But you can loop through it with

```
for (var key in data) {
    // your code ....
}
```

**Edit: Answer to your comment**

You can still use an `Object` by simply use this style

```
 {'data': { /* your json data */ }} // when there's data 
 {'data': null}                     // when no data available
```

Then in your function.

```
if (data.data) {
    for(var key in data.data) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Comment: So should I change the methodology to return Arrays and not objects?

Comment: @BostonMacOSX You still can use an `Object`. Here's my method

`    
    {'data': { /* your json data */ }}  // when there's data
    {'data': null}                      // when no data available
`
Then in your code you can simply check
`
    if (data.data) {
        // your code
    }
`